# Colocar um botão de desligar serviço na notificação de um App Android

Tags: android, android-notification

Na minha aplicação tenho um Service rodando em background, o qual coloca uma notificação na Status Bar do usuário, gostaria de adicionar um botão para desligar o serviço, como o Waze app de mapas faz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um *BroadcastReceiver* com o código necessário para parar o serviço.
Ao criar a notificação use o método [addAction()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) do *Notification.Builder* passando um *PendigIntent* que lance esse *BroadcastReceiver*.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Parar serviço", pIntent).build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = 
  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Outra forma seria o *PendigIntent* ser contruido de forma a lançar o serviço passando um *'Extra'* que indicasse que o serviço deve ser parado.
O método `onStartCommand()` do serviço verifica esse *'Extra'* e chama `stopSelf()`.

O *PendigIntent* a usar no `addAction()` seria assim:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, oSeuServico.class);
Intent.putExtra("Parar","Sim");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Certo, e o ícone de desligar na notificação como posso fazer?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com uma outra forma de fazer. O ícone é um *drawable*. No código que postei é `R.drawable.icon`, o primeiro parâmetro de `addAction`.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado! Já estou implementando aqui, acredito que vai dar certo :)

Comment: Outra coisa, tem hora que o action mostra, tem hora que não, quando tem muitas notificações, tem como determinar para sempre mostrar o action?

Comment: O que é que não mostra? O ícone de desligar ou a notificação toda?

Comment: Exato, coloquei a prioridade como máxima da notificação agora aparece.

Comment: Consegui implementar até a parte do BroadCastReceiver, agora eu gostaria de fechar toda aplicação, no broadcast..Algo como finish(); para fechar todo app.

Comment: Se o BroadcastReceiver for uma *inner* classe da sua *activity* você tem acesso ao método `finish()`. No entanto não faz muito sentido usar *notifications* para "parar" o serviço se a sua *activity* tem de se manter em execução enquanto o serviço estiver em funcionamento.